# Is there a reason to individualize Django class based views?

Tags: python, django, django-views

In a Django tutorial I am watching someone writes:

```
class GetUserProfileView(APIView):
     def get(self, request, format=None):
          # user profile get code

class UpdateProfileView(APIView):
     def put(self, request, format=None):
          # user profile put code
```

whereas to me a beginner it seems to make way more sense to organize it in one view:

```
class ProfileView(APIView):
     def get(self, request, format=None):
          # user profile get code

     def put(self, request, format=None):
          # user profile put code
```

Is there a reason for organizing them into different views or is the tutorial maker unexperienced?

Comment: The latter eventually leads to a `ViewSet`, which is the most common use case of the Django Rest framework, so you need some patience :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually such views are indeed grouped, that concept is called a [**`ViewSet`** <sup>[drf-doc]</sup>](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/), which can group a `list` (usually a GET request without any "key" for an object), `retrieve` (usually a GET request with a key for which we retrieve an item), `create` (usually a POST request), `update` (usually a PUT request), `partial_update` (usually a PATCH request), and `destroy` (usually a DELETE request).

Typically one only uses an `APIView` in case it is not a "default" scenario like retrieving the objects, serializing these, and returning these. So only if you do something more sophisticated. One often uses different `APIView`s for example if the serializer or other logic is different depending on the scenario, in that case often the logic will disambiguate betwen the scenarios often making it less elegant than splitting it in different classes.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, each developer has its own style of writing and organizing the code.

In your case, adhering to such Principles of Clean Code as **DRY** and **KISS** I would suggest using this style:

```py
class UserProfileView(APIView):
     def get(self, request, format=None):
          # user profile get code

     def put(self, request, format=None):
          # user profile put code
```

which eliminates the duplication and redundancy of class-based views and makes your code cleaner. (and which I always use ;)